# Smooth transition between 3 cameras with Cinemachine and Timeline

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine, unity-timeline

I'm trying to achieve a simple but smooth camera movement with Cinemachine and using Timeline, cause it really helps me to tweak things really quickly.

The movement is easy to achieve with an animator an building a keyframed clip, the result should be something like [this](https://streamable.com/drmhr1).

The way that I've tried to achieve it without an animator and clips, using Cinemachine and Timelines is to put 3 VirtualCameras, and let the timeline make the blendings, it looks like [this](https://streamable.com/kjsmxj), but as you can see, between second and third position, the camera STOPS, just a frame, but it stops, and looks clunky.

The main though about this is that as the blending is just between 2 cameras, not 3, it looks like this, but I don't know how to achieve it just with 2 cameras, cause I've tried and it looks like [this](https://streamable.com/7fsg33).

The other way is to use a Dolly camera, but is harder (and slower) to proceduralize movements.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Or how to achieve this without the need of creating custom animation clips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gregoryl from Cinemachine, the easiest solution is this one:

Use 2 cameras, give them a LookAt target and set the `BlendHint` option as `Cylindrical Position` under `Transitions`.

[image]

With that change the transition will be a nice orbit around the target, instead of standard linear lerp. Something like [this](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/cylindrical-gif.632159/).